# Using sum() to print the sum of even numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble finding information on using sum to take from a list. I know how to use sum with range, for example:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(50):
    sum=sum + i
print (sum)
```

But I can't get my code to work when I am using a list such as `[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10]` and taking the even numbers using `sum`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am also new to this site, so if someone could edit my post putting it into the code format, that would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: You are not using `sum()` at all, you are *shadowing* the built-in `sum` with an accumulator variable...

Comment: Instead of showing code that you know works, you should show the code that you are having problems with ;)

Comment: In other words, please [edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `filter` out odd-values:

```
def is_even(x):
    # if the remainder (modulo) is 0 then it's evenly divisible by 2 => even
    return x % 2 == 0  

def sum_of_evens(it):
    return sum(filter(is_even, it))

>>> sum_of_evens([1,2,3,4,5])
6
```

Or if you prefer a conditional generator expression:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> sum(item for item in lst if item % 2 == 0)
6
```

Or the explicit (long) approach:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
sum_ = 0
for item in lst:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        sum_ += item
print(sum_)   # 6
```